# i want to import excel file data into django database table,how to solve below errors?

Tags: python, django

```
class office(models.Model):
    office_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length = 200)


class employees(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     designation = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     officeid = models.ForeignKey(office,on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name = 'emp')
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import office,employees
from import_export import resources
from tablib import Dataset

class Simple_import(APIView):
    def post(self,request):   
        if request.method == 'POST':
            employees_resource = EmployeesResource()
            dataset = Dataset()
            new_persons = request.FILES['myfile']
            imported_data = dataset.load(new_persons.read())
            result = employees_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  
            # Test the data import

        if not result.has_errors():
            employees_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)
            # Actually import now
        return render(request,'info/index.html')`
```

**index.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}`
    <input id = "myfile" type="file" name="myfile">
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

if i click upload button
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh3Xg.png)

i got an error above shown in that image how to solve that error??

Comment: you need a post method in your Simple_import class. Follow the docs https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/#rewriting-our-api-using-class-based-views

Comment: "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." i am getting this error now

Comment: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}

Comment: so get method is for get request and post method is for post request. If you are using both the request method, then you need both of them.

Comment: it leads to MultiValueDictKeyError at /reports/import/
'myfile'

Comment: update your code

Comment: can u post the traceback?

Comment: this error shows up in terminal new_persons = request.FILES['myfile']
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'myfile'

Comment: try request.FILES.getlist('myfile')

Comment: Nope it leads to 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
error